# Extracting bool from istream in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, boolean, istream, istringstream

I'm converting my fields class read functions into one template function.  I have field classes for `int, unsigned int, long,` and `unsigned long`.  These all use the same method for extracting a value from an `istringstream` (only the types change):

```
template <typename Value_Type>
Value_Type Extract_Value(const std::string& input_string)
{
    std::istringstream    m_string_stream;
    m_string_stream.str(input_string);
    m_string_stream.clear();
    m_string_stream >> value;
    return;
}
```

The tricky part is with the `bool` (Boolean) type.  There are many textual representations for Boolean:
`0, 1, T, F, TRUE, FALSE`, *and all the case insensitive combinations*

Here's the questions:

1. What does the C++ standard say are
   valid data to extract a `bool`,
   using the stream extraction
   operator?
2. Since Boolean can be represented by
   text, does this involve `locale`s?
3. Is this platform dependent?

I would like to simplify my code by not writing my own handler for `bool` input.

I am using MS Visual Studio 2008 (version 9), C++, and Windows XP and Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings for true and false are defined by `std::numpunct::truename()` and `std::numpunct::falsename()`. You can get the `numpunct` for a given stream with `use_facet <numpunct <char> >(stream.getloc())`, if I understand the documentation correctly.

EDIT: You can toggle whether to use `"1"`/`"0"` or `"true"`/`"false` with `std::noboolalpha` and `std::boolalpha`.

Comment: Is this case insensitive?  
Is this in a specific version / revision of the C++ language?

Comment: Since the default values are "true" and "false", I'm going to assume that it's case sensitive. Also, I'm going to assume it's been in the standard for a while.